# WPF - html format text block wpf

Tags: c#, html, wpf, formatting, textblock

I'm working on WPF application that summarizes different kind analysis and display the results in a text block.
The issue is that the output is a long string builder that at the end of the analysis I just convert it to a string and update it as the text of the relevant text block.
Is there any way to edit some HTML tags inside the string builder and once I set it as the text of the text block the colors will be shown in the UI?
(text block is not mandatory, any sort of text container in WPF can be a solution).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: see this article: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1097390/Displaying-HTML-in-a-WPF-RichTextBox

Answer (score 2):

If you're working on WPF's UI with XAML, you can use

```
<TextBlock>
  <Run x:Name="Name" foreground="red"/>
  <Run x:Name="OtherProperty" foreground="#1f1f1f"/>
</TextBlock>
```

This is like HTML's span for XAML provided you pass the different strings to Run instead of just a single string with string builder

Name.Text = "Generic Name"; //for example.
You can edit the colour from code behind too if you intend to

Comment: It should me more dynamically.. not to limit the text block to only two run objects. I'm just asking if there is anyway to do it by additional tags that will let me the option to edit and do different kind of formats.

Comment: Take a look at RichTextBlock https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.RichTextBlock
Not sure if it works on WPF as well, but if not, there's definitely a control for it by syncfusion